# Change color of specific language words in visual studio code with textMateRules

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vhdl, syntax-highlighting

I want to change the color of some of the VHDL operators colors in VS code, is there a simple way of doing that in the settings.json?

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Visual Studio Dark]": {
            "variables": "#ffae00",
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "keyword.operator",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FF0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": [
                        "keyword.reserved.vhdl",

                    ],                    
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#1eff00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

That generates the next ouput:

[image: vhdl formatted]

And for example I would like to be able to separate the vhdl struct reserved words like (end, entity, architecture, process, if, then, else) from logic operators (not), in green.
Or the assignations (<=) from the (;) or the ({})

If tried many things but, I'm not able to insert as condition a pattern.
And I don't have time to go with the example : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide, maybe in the future

Thanks

Comment: Try https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#tokens-and-scopes the scope inspector.  If they have different scopes you are in luck, if they have the same scope you can't do it via textmate rules.

Comment: I was able to change color to the words in different scopes, but I want to change to the ones in the same scope, so now I will have to search how to change words from scope, because all the vhdl specific words are in the same "reserved.vhdl" scope